# Classifying image by file extension within a PDF creator

Tags: c#, strings, .net, image, pdf

To create a `pdfDocument` I am using following code which works as expected but do not want to use multiple if else.

Any patterns or any design strategies? It may  be a over do for the example , but will be useful.

```
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
string outPutPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".pdf";

Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf pdfConverter = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();

Section pdfSection = pdfConverter.Sections.Add();

//Table pdfTable = new Table() { DefaultCellBorder=new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.BorderInfo((int)BorderSide.All,0.1F)};

//pdfSection.Paragraphs.Add(pdfTable);

Image sourceImage = new Image();
sourceImage.ImageInfo.File = fileName;



if (fileExtension == ".jpg" || fileExtension == ".jpeg")
{
    sourceImage.ImageInfo.ImageFileType = ImageFileType.Jpeg;
}
else if (fileExtension == ".bmp")
{
    sourceImage.ImageInfo.ImageFileType = ImageFileType.Bmp;
}
else if (fileExtension == ".gif")
{
    sourceImage.ImageInfo.ImageFileType = ImageFileType.Gif;
}
else if (fileExtension == ".png")
{
    sourceImage.ImageInfo.ImageFileType = ImageFileType.Png;
}
else if (fileExtension == ".tiff")
{
    sourceImage.ImageInfo.ImageFileType = ImageFileType.Tiff;
}

pdfSection.Paragraphs.Add(sourceImage);

pdfConverter.Save(outPutPath);
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to avoid an `if else`. You could use a switch if you wanted, but either is fine.

Answer (score 14):

Naturally, you can use a dictionary to map extensions to file types:

- "jpg" -> `ImageFileType.Jpeg`
- "jpeg" -> `ImageFileType.Jpeg`
- "bmp" -> `ImageFileType.Bmp`
- "gif" -> `ImageFileType.Gif`
- ... and so on

If the key `fileExtension` exists in the dictionary, you set `sourceImage.ImageInfo.ImageFileType` to the mapped file type, otherwise simply do nothing.
That will get rid of all the if-else.

Answer (score 3):

## Enum.TryParse

I couldn't find the definition of `ImageFileType` but if this is your own type then you can parse the extensions directly as an enum. You just need to remove the `.` before doing this.

```
var imageFileType = ImageFileType.Undefined;
var parsed = Enum.TryParse<ImageFileType>(
    value: "jpg", 
    ignoreCase: true, 
    result: out imageFileType);
```

where

```
enum ImageFileType
{ 
    Undefined, // Unknown, None, etc. whatever you like
    Jpeg,
    Jpg = Jpeg,
    Png,
    //..
}
```

---

## ImageFileType property

You set the file name via `ImageInfo.File` and then the extension... this is a little be weird. The `ImageInfo` class should be able to recognize the extension which means that the `ImageFileType` property should be read-only and return the type of the image:

```
class ImageInfo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public ImageFileType ImageFileType 
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"You need to set the {nameof(FileName)} property first.");
            }
            var imageFileType = ImageFileType.Undefined;
            var parsed = Enum.TryParse<ImageFileType>(
                value: Path.GetExtension(File).Substring(1), 
                ignoreCase: true, 
                result: out imageFileType);
            return imageFileType;
        }
    }
}
```